# StackOverflowError in java - Recursion

Tags: java, constructor, stack-overflow

I'm new to java, I would like to understand when I crate object in class and main program  I'm getting this exception **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError** while executing below program. Can someone please help me to understand why its going in recursion?

```
public class Test {

    Test t = new Test();

    public static void main(String arg[]) {

        Test t = new Test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a constructor there.  I think the following is what you want:

```
class Test {
  //constructor method
  Test() {
    System.out.println("Constructor method called.");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test;  //creating object
  }
}
```

Source:  http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/tutorial/java-constructor-tutorial

The reason you're getting a stack overflow is that every time your class is instantiated it declares instance variable t which is initialized to another new instance of the class, which results in an infinite recursion since each new object creates another new object, etc.

Comment: In java if you don't declare a constructor is fine, the default constructor will be included by the compiler.

Comment: Yeah I know, but it seemed useful to output a message to prove the constructor was called, since poster said he was trying to understand constructors.

Comment: That source I quoted may not be the best for general java tutorials.  This one's probably better, although the constructor example is not as simple:    https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the variable `t`.

If a new `Test`-Object is created, `t` is initialized automatically - with a new `Test`-Object, which on creation again creates a new `Test`-Object. So each call to the constructor of `Test` leads to another call of the constructor of `Test`. Until the stack overflows.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are declairing `Test t = new Test();` in the test class itself remove the top `Test t = new Test();` or change the variable and then try run it.